# Pandas send Multiple DataFrames to CSV with For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop, dataframe

I have two symbols with price data and successfully imported/modified that price data, for each symbol/respective DataFrame, as shown below:

```
assets = ['ES','VX']
path = r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\%s\*.csv"

files = []
for a in assets:
    files.extend(glob.iglob(path % a))

df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]

for b in df_list:
    b['Returns'] = b['Close'].pct_change()

#Do Some stuff to DF, but not relevant to exporting the file 

end_path_to_csv = "C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\%s\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\blah.csv" 

for p, c in zip(assets, df_list):
    c.to_csv(end_path_to_csv % p)
```

The DataFrames look as they should, here are sample for each symbol:

VX:

```html
Index Ticker Date Close Returns
0 VX 3/14/17 4:29 AM 16.35 NaN
1 VX 3/14/17 6:29 AM 16.46 0.006728
2 VX 3/14/17 7:29 AM 16.45 -0.000608
3 VX 3/14/17 8:29 AM 16.47 0.001216
4 VX 3/14/17 9:29 AM 16.4 -0.00425
```

ES:

```html
 Ticker Date Close Returns
0 ES U7 3/14/2017 2365.5 NaN
1 ES U7 3/14/2017 2362.25 -0.001374
2 ES U7 3/14/2017 2355 -0.003069
3 ES U7 3/14/2017 2359.25 0.001805
4 ES U7 3/14/2017 2356 -0.001378
```

However, when I check the CSV files (no errors) the 'VX' folder/file has only ES data. So the VX dataframe created from the 'assets' list is not being sent to to the folder as intended. Instead the ES file is being sent there.

I think the issue is in my last for loop referencing assets (a list) against a 2-part list of dataframes (df_list). I've tried using a dictionary to match 'assets' to 'df_list' but am unable to pass the for loop by doing so. How can I get the VX DataFrame to go to the VX folder/file instead of the ES going there?

Comment: How many data frames are in df_list? By your use of iglob I am assuming more than two. If that is the case, then the zip() function will stop after the assets list is exhausted (2 iterations). If there are more than two data frames in df_list with ES data, then the first will be put in the ES folder and the second in the VX folder.

Comment: Please show more of your actual code. Posted code is not enough to help per your explanation, especially file name and extension: `...\\blah.csv`.

Comment: Have the folders been created already?